# Выбрать 50% от результирующей таблицы

Tags: mysql

```
select 50 percent skills / stage from personal order by skills / stage;
```

`skills` - колонка
`stage` - колонка

Answer (score 1):

Можно 2 запросами. Сначала выбрать количество всех:

```
select count(skills) from `personal `;
```

Присваиваем переменной, значение делим на 2. А потом выборка по лимиту:

```
select 50 percent skills / stage from personal order by skills / stage limit 0,переменная;
```

Comment: Можно уточнить запрос?

Comment: А

    $res=db_select("select count(skills) from personal"); /* db_select - функция подключения к базе */
    $z=mysql_fetch_array($res); /*получаем общее количество записей */
    $new_z=$z/2;
    $res=db_select("select * skills from personal order by skills limit 0,$new_z");

Comment: Мне для лабораторной надо 1 запросом.  
Лаба на джаве.